# problems with simple library in javascript Error: "implicitly has an 'any' type."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, typescript, npm

I'm trying to create a library in javascript that makes some requests to an API, I want to create a module that I can publish in npm and that can be used from any framework like angular or react
I have the following code of my class with these files to publish it

masivPushWebService.js

```
import { MANAGMENT_API_URL, WEB_PLATFORM } from './constants.js';
import { sendPost } from './httpUtils.js';

class masivPushWebService {

    constructor(externalApplicationId) {
        this.externalApplicationId = externalApplicationId;
    }

    async registerToken(payload) {
        let body = {
            token: payload,
            platform: WEB_PLATFORM,
            externalApplicationId: this.externalApplicationId
        }
        const response = await sendPost(MANAGMENT_API_URL + "tokens", body)
        return response
    }

}

export default masivPushWebService;
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "npm-servtest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "src/masivPushWebService.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
}
```

When I publish it, it publishes without problems, however when I install it, for example in an Angular project, it gives me the following error

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'npm-servtest'. '.../masivPushWebService.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
> Try `npm i --save-dev @types/npm-servtest` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'npm-servtest';

I am not an expert in front and I have tried to find the solution but I can't find it, could you help me?

I tried to place the tsconfig.json file but it did not solve the problem

Comment: As the error suggest, you should add a typescript declaration file (d.ts) then add it to your package json

Answer (score 0):

First of all, remove your `tsconfig.json`, you don't need one if you are not using TypeScript.

Second thing, mind how you import your library in your angular project. It should look like this:

```
import masivPushWebService from 'library';
```

If you are exporting some global variable in your library you may also need:

```
declare const globalVar: any;
```

Third, you should change your `tsconfig.json` in order to not make it check external libraries. Your Angular application shouldn't care if any external library doesn't follow your configuration. To do this you need to add this line:

```
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
```